# Issues with SOAP in non-WSDL mode

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I am making a simple web service for communication between two sites I own.

Since it is only a basic application, I've been working without a WSDL file, so in `non-WSDL mode` as the PHP manual calls it.

This is basically what the client-side looks like:

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => $location, 'uri' => '', 'trace' => TRUE));

$res = $client->__soapCall('myFunc', array($param));
```

On the server-side, I have a function called `myFunc`:

```
$soap = new SoapServer(null, array('uri' => ''));

$soap->addFunction('myFunc');

//Use the request to invoke the service
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $soap->handle();
}
```

When I actually try invoking the `myFunc` function, I get and error:

```
Function 'ns1:myFunc' doesn't exist
```

For some reason, the soap server is prepending `ns1:` to the function name!

Using `$client->__getLastRequest()`, I get:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:getTopElement>
        <param0 xsi:type="xsd:string">rightcolBox</param0>
    </ns1:getTopElement>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

I'm not a SOAP expert, but it seems to me that the client is causing the error in making the request - or is the server misinterpreting it?

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. When I set SoapClient options' uri to not null, the problem was solved.

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => $location, 'uri' => 'foo', 'trace' => TRUE));
```

Yes, it can be any string, even "foo" as in this example.

Comment: For some strange reason on Windows PHP allowed blank `uri` to work but it doesn't work on Linux - could be the PHP version. However I also found out that after setting the `uri` to 'foo' for client it worked like a charm. This issue plagued me for days thanks a lot for your help.